# Splitting a big json file into smaller json files on AWS Lambda and save it on S3

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Let assume this is a big file.

I want to split the file into multiple chunks.
An example will be if I have a JSON file of 500 MB and I want to split it into different chunks.
The maximum acceptable file size is 30 MB (30000000 bytes).
This function runs on an aws lambda and the result should be saved on the s3 bucket.
Please how can I do this?

```json
{
   "start":"HelloI",
   "users": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough"
    }
  },
  {
   ...
  }
]
}
```

Here is my code.
I believe I am doing something wrong.
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you.

```py
json_size = 50580490;
MIN_SIZE = 30000000;
data_len = len(file)

get_array_length = len(file["users"])

print("Print data len : ",data_len)
print("Print  Get Array length  : ", get_array_length)

items = []
if isinstance(file, dict):
  print('Valid JSON file found')

  # determine number of files necessary
  split_into_files = math.ceil(json_size/MIN_SIZE)
  print(f'File will be split into {split_into_files} equal parts')

  split_data = [[] for i in range(0,split_into_files)]
  print('split_data : ', split_data)

  starts = [math.floor(i * get_array_length/split_into_files) for i in range(0,split_into_files)]
  starts.append(data_len)
  print('starts : ', starts)

  for i in range(0,split_into_files):
    for n in range(starts[i], starts[i+1]):
      print('The value for N is: ' , n)     
      print("split_data[i] :" , split_data[i])
      #print(file["users"][n])
      split_data[i].append(file["users"][n])
      print(split_data[i])
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Why do you believe you're doing something wrong? Do you get no output? Wrong output? Does it throw an error? "Here's my code, fix it for me" is not suitable here. Please try some [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), narrow your problem down to a [mre], and ask a _specific_ question about the problem you're facing with your code.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Look, I am not asking you to fix the code for me.
I meant I might be going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution**
Probably not the best one but it works.

```py
import json
import boto3
import os
import time
import math


# Variable definition.
SESSION_STORAGE = os.environ['JSON_BUCKET']
SESSION = boto3.session.Session()
CURRENT_REGION = SESSION.region_name
S3_CLIENT = boto3.client("s3")
MIN_SIZE = 16000000 # 16 mb

def handler(event, context):
    
    # Instantiate start time.
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # Bucket Name where file was uploaded
    #bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    bucket = 'json-upload-bucket' # => testing bucket.
    
    #file_key_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'] # Use this to make it dynamic.
    file_key_name = 'XXXXXXXXX-users.json' # This is for testing only. 
    print("File Key Name", file_key_name)
    
    response = S3_CLIENT.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key_name)
    #print("Response : ", response)
    
    # json size 
    json_size = response['ContentLength']
    print("json_size : ", json_size)
    
    # Reading content
    content = response['Body']
    jsonObject = json.loads(content.read())
    data = jsonObject['users']
    data_len = len(jsonObject)
    #print('Length of JSON : ', data_len)
    #print('Order array length : ', len(data))
    
    if isinstance(data, list):
        data_len = len(data)
        print('Valid JSON file found')
        
        if(json_size <=  MIN_SIZE): 
            print('File meets the minimum size.')
        else:
            # determine number of files necessary
            split_into_files = math.ceil(json_size/MIN_SIZE)
            print(f'File will be split into {split_into_files} equal parts')
            
            # initialize 2D array
            split_data = [[] for i in range(0,split_into_files)]
            
            # determine indices of cutoffs in array
            starts = [math.floor(i * data_len/split_into_files) for i in range(0,split_into_files)]
            starts.append(data_len)
            
            # loop through 2D array
            for i in range(0,split_into_files):
                # loop through each range in array
                for n in range(starts[i],starts[i+1]):
                    split_data[i].append(data[n])
                
                
                print(file_key_name.split('.')[0] + '_' + str(i+1) + '.json')
                name = os.path.basename(file_key_name).split('.')[0] + '_' + str(i+1) + '.json'
                print('Name : ', name)
                folder = '/tmp/'+name
                with open(folder, 'w') as outfile:
                    
                    # restructure the json back to its original state.
                    generated_json = {
                        list(jsonObject.keys())[0] : list(jsonObject.values())[0],
                        list(jsonObject.keys())[1] : split_data[i]}
                    json.dump(generated_json, outfile, indent=4)
                    
                S3_CLIENT.upload_file(folder, bucket, name)
                    
                print('Part',str(i+1),'... completed')
            
    else:
        print("JSON is not an Array of Objects")

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('JSON split completed checks s3.')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its seems you are splitting the data in raw form, means the json is hierarchical structure and when you split directly your data it wont recognize the records instead it may break the structure.

You can read the users elements into any other structure like list/data frames first.

```
with open('users.json','r') as f:
    user_list = json.load(f)
    users_data = user_list['users']
```

(you need to start reading from users list in json file as you have another column in file - like 'starts')

Then you will have all the records in  users_data,then based on json record count you can split accordingly.
If you want to add some performance in this process for future usage - you can sort the records in users_data and split the records into separate json file.